# jQuery - delaying all functions calls declared with .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the .on() function in jQuery to assign functions to events.

```
var someEvent = getEventName(someParams); // gets the event, like 'click'

var someFunctionReference = getFunctionNameBasedOnParams(someParams); // gets the function reference

$('.myElement').on(someEvent, someFunctionReference);
```

What I would like to do is wrap 'someFunctionReference' inside a timeout or delay its firing (by some time; lets say 250ms) without having to go and modify every single function that is returned by the method.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just modify the code in `getFunctionNameBasedOnParams` so that it returns a function wrapped in a delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you can't modify the code in `getFunctionNameBasedOnParams`, so all you need to do is create another function that returns a function wrapped in a timer.

```
function delayFunc(fn, ms) {
    return function() {
        var args = arguments;
        setTimeout(function() {
            fn.apply(this, args);
        }, isNaN(ms) ? 100 : ms);
    }
}
```

Then pass your function to it.

```
var someFunctionReference = delayFunc(getFunctionNameBasedOnParams(someParams), 250);
```

Be aware that your handler's return value is now meaningless, so if you `return false`, it'll have no effect.